# Selecting other anchors inside the same unordered list item

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have many `li` elements in an `ul` list like below:

```
<li id="filesOrderArray_dynamic_number>">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove_from_filestock">
    <img src="ui_icons/cross-small.gif" title="Remove" rel="more_dynamic_numbers_here" />
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="title_filestock">
    <img src="ui_icons/properties-small.gif')?>" title="Properties" rel="more_dynamic_numbers_here" />
  </a>
  <a href="some_address" target="_blank" class="filestock_preview fancybox" rel="filestock">
    Some Title
  </a>
</li>
```

I have a jQuery function. I am trying to select the `a.filestock_preview` text when I click the `a.title_filestock` inside the same `li` tag.

```
function title()
{
  $('a.title_filestock').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).closest('a.filestock_preview').text(); alert(value);   
  });
}
title();
```

Comment: @James Allardice, Thanks for corrections, noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.closest()` method looks at *ancestor* elements. The `.filestock_preview` element you want to select is a *sibling* of the `.title_filestock` element. Since it immediately follows it, you can use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
var value = $(this).next().text();
```

You could alternatively use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and pass in the selector:

```
var value = $(this).siblings('a.filestock_preview').text();
```